# Can't get a valid response from a REST web service using System.Net.Http.HttpClient

Tags: c#, rest, httpclient

I am using this test method (and helper class) to verify the response from an external web service:

```
[TestMethod]
public void WebServiceReturnsSuccessResponse()
{
    using (var provider = new Provider(new Info()))
    using (var result = provider.GetHttpResponseMessage())
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(result.IsSuccessStatusCode);
    }
}

private class Info : IInfo
{
    public string URL { get; set; } =
        "https://notreallythe.website.com:99/service/";
    public string User { get; set; } = "somename";
    public string Password { get; set; } = "password1";
}
```

I can't get this test to pass; I always get a `500 - Internal Server Error` result.  I have connected via an external utility (Postman) - so the web service is up and I can connect with the url & credentials that I have.

I think the problem is in my instantiation of the HttpClient class, but I can't determine where.  I am using Basic authentication:

```
public class Provider : IProvider, IDisposable 
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    public Provider(IInfo config){
        if (config == null) 
           throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(config));

        var userInfo = new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes($"{config.User}:{config.Password}");

        _httpClient = new HttpClient
        {
            BaseAddress = new Uri(config.URL),
            DefaultRequestHeaders =
            {
                Accept = { new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml")},
                Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(
                   "Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(userInfo)),
                ExpectContinue = false,                 
            },
         };
    }

    public HttpResponseMessage GetHttpResponseMessage()
    {
        return _httpClient.GetAsync("1234").Result;
    }
}
```

The response I get back appears to go to the correct endpoint; the RequestUri in the response looks exactly like I expect, `https://notreallythe.website.com:99/service/1234`.

Comment: Could the problem be the missing opening brace in `var userInfo = new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes($"config.User}:{config.Password}");
`?

Comment: Also, "you are using HttpClient wrong and it's destabilizing your software": https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/

Comment: @RobertHarvey no, I just got over-zealous with my redacting to genericize the names.

Comment: @WiktorZychla Actually, I'm only instantiating `Provider` once.  I need to refactor to make it a singleton, but thanks for the tip.

Comment: So it works in PostMan but not in your test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to load up [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and do a recording of the HTTP traffic when this operation succeeds (through the browser).

Then, load up your code, stand up another instance (or window) of Fiddler, and do the same thing with your code.  Now, compare the two Fiddler windows to see what is different.

You only need to compare those things in Fiddler that are highlighted in blue.  You can ignore the other communications.

Comment: The smartass in me that just wants the damned thing to work is screaming "GREAT!  Yet ANOTHER third party tool I have to spend a day figuring out!!"  - but I do appreciate the suggestion.  Thank you.

Comment: I don't make this suggestion lightly.  It took me awhile to get comfortable with Fiddler, but trust me, analyzing the HTTP traffic (and the cookies, etc.) is the only meaningful way to diagnose problems like this.

Comment: **Handy Tip:** you can enable and disable recording by clicking the box in the lower left-hand corner of Fiddler.